# How can I integrate simba jdbc bigquery driver with java play framework?

Tags: playframework, google-bigquery

I need to get data using google's bigquery into my application.

Comment: Try to be more specific, this helps us helping you... What have you researched and tried already?

Comment: I am getting jackson conflict during compile time

Comment: >java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Comment: using sbt for dependency injection